# moving series from one chart to another

Tags: lightningchart

I have Single dashboard with multiple charts.And each chart have multiple series.

Let us say chart1 and chart2

Now is there anyway to move all series and data from one chart to another ? I want to move  all the series (lines and scatters) from chart1 to chart2 , And I want to clear the series in chart1 , which I can do with **.dispose** method.

```
  lightningChart().Dashboard({
    container: container,
    numberOfRows: 2,
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    theme: theme,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no utility for this kind of application, so you'll have to go with the simple solution of removing the moved series and recreating them from scratch in the other chart.

The `dispose` approach for removing the moved series is correct.

For implementation, I'd advise to maintain some data structure for every series and the data it contains. Then you can recreate it and show the same data relatively simply.