# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: lightningchart

I upgraded to version 4 and I am getting this error , But I have no idea where its coming from

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0.

Its coming around axis = chart.addAxisY(true);
```

But my chart and everything is created .

Finally found where the bug is happening , if I remove this part that error is not coming , is anything depreciated in below code in version 4 ?

```
   lastsignalname = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, { x: axisX, y: axisY })
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like something unexpected happening when chart height is 0 pixels. Could you check if that is the case? And would help to know if you are using some frontend framework like React/Vue/etc.

Comment: hi , finally found that bug is coming at addUIElement , is this depreciated in v4 ?

Comment: It is not deprecated. Any input on previous question?

Comment: No Idea , I rolled back to 3.40 , 3.40 was faster than 4.0.

Comment: v4.0.0 is slightly faster than v3.4.0 (with effects disabled, which is quite easy to do https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.1/index.html#q-how-can-i-disable-glow-or-shadow-effects).

Comment: is this correct db.createChartXY({
                    theme: disableThemeEffects(Themes.darkGold), ?

Comment: I tried it again after disabling them effects.., the 100's of lines and bands I use to draw in 3.40 is much faster and very slow in version 4  , also my custom zooming in and out is so slow in version 4 .. please make it smooth like 3.4 in upcoming release

Comment: this code is what I use - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642909/drag-the-chart-of-lightningchart-programatically , in version 4 its very buggy..

Comment: The linked code uses old syntax which should not work in v4.0.0. Please carefully study the migration guide. https://lightningchart.com/wp-content/uploads/LightningChart-JS-Migration-Guide-3x-to-4-0-0.pdf
I locally tested the adjusted code and had no problems.

Comment: All of our performance testing indicates that v4.0.0 is faster than v3.4.0. Not by a whole lot, but still clearly faster. If you can clearly reproduce a performance degradation, I would suggest raising a question over it, with materials we can use to confirm it.

Comment: @NiiloKeinänen , can you update the answer for version 4.0.0 in same question , thanks.